# regex matching <value> with a CRLF

Tags: c#, regex, pattern-matching, web-crawler, newline

I'm trying to crawl a web page and get all interesting elements with a regex including the following term:

```
<font\s+face=""Arial"">(?<value>.+)</font>
```

I don't understand very well why there is an **"?"** before my **"< value >"**, if someone could explain me (this syntax works).

for each matching expression, I get my value like that:

```
var value = m.Groups["value"].Value;
```

My only problem is when my **< value >** includes a **CRLF** this is not matching even if I specify "`RegexOptions.Multiline`" in C#.

Thank's for your answers.

Comment: Or you could use the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) and get accurate results...

Answer (score 1):

The parenthesis are the matching part of the regex, `(?<name>pattern)` assigns a name to the matching parenthesis, that is why you can refer to the match with `...Groups["value"]...` instead of the number of the match, as is otherwise usual with regexps

Use `RegexOptions.SingleLine` to solve your problem; (DOTALL in other regexp flavours).

To clarify: `RegexOption.MultiLine` changes the meaning of `^` and `$`, `RegexOptions.SingleLine` the meaning of `.`; I found a full list here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using this syntax:

```
(?<value>.+(\n.*)?)
```

but now I don't understand an other thing. Why when I have this string:

```
style='font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; mso-bidi-font-size:10.0pt;mso-bidi-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>Milord</span></b></p>
```

The term "Milord" is not matching in < value > with this pattern:

```
style='font\-family\:Arial;\s+font\-size\:10pt;\s+mso\-bidi\-font\-size\:10\.0pt;mso\-bidi\-font-family\:\n?"Times\s+New\s+Roman"'>(<font\s+face="Arial">?)(?<value>.+(\n.*)?)(</font>?)</span></b></p>
```

while I have specified these strings as optional

```
(<font\s+face="Arial">?)
(</font>?)
```

I really don't understand, I tried so many syntax with different places for the "?" and nothing is my expected result!

Comment: Don't ask a qustion as answer to your own question please; edit your original question to reflect your new understanding of the problem.

Comment: in both the parenthesis the ? makes the smallest possible pattern in front of it optional, in this case both times the `>` -- you want non-matching grouping, that's in most flavours `(?:<fontBLAHl">)?`, notice the position of the second `?`?  Read up on regex syntax, please. I recommend the "owl" book by o'reilly as excellent resource and learning material.

Answer (score -1):

Dialects of `Regex` differ, but for your **newline** issue, look for a `Regex` flags called either `MULTILINE` and/or `DOTALL`.

If the only problem is with line breaks, one of those should fix it.

I can't answer the angle brackets part, I think it's specific to your dialect of `Regex` as well (in C#)

Comment: I solved my problem using this syntax:
    (?<value>.+(\n.*)?)